# Django Custom Authentication - BaseUserManager's create_user not being used

Tags: python, django, authentication

I customizes Django's authentication and now every time I try to create a new user using Django Admin this user's password is saved directly, without being hashed. I found out that create_user method from BaseUserManager class is not being called. When I create a superuser using bash it is done properly. Is there anything wrong with my model?

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.BaseAccount'
```

apps/authentication/models.py

```
class BaseAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
   def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
      if not email:
          raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address.')

      account = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email)
      )
      account.set_password(password)
      account.save()

   return account

   def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
      account = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)

      account.is_admin = True
      account.is_staff = True
      account.save()

   return account

class BaseAccount(AbstractBaseUser):
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)

   is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   objects = BaseAccountManager()

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.email

   def get_full_name(self):
      return ' '.join([self.first_name, self.last_name])

   def get_short_name(self):
      return self.first_name

   def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
      return self.is_admin

   def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
      return self.is_admin
```

Comment: It sounds like your model admin might be inheriting from `ModelAdmin`, so it is missing the code that sets the password properly.

Answer (score 3):

For future readers, because this issue also got me banging my head against the wall...

To access that precious `create_user()` method from anywhere in your django project :

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class SomeClass():
    # This could be a form, for example...
    def some_function():
        get_user_model().objects.create_user()
```

If you call it from the `save()` method of some custom form, please take proper care of the `commit` parameter, and don't forget to register your custom user model in the settings.py file, as per the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to your question about passwords, but I still don't know how to get the create_user function to be called correctly.  The example removes username in favor of just an email.  I am still looking for a way to hit the create_user function defined in the custom UserManager inerhiting from BaseUserManager.  My custom manager sends an email with a password reset link and a one time token... which would avoid the need to actually set a hashed password from django admin.

https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/08/07/migrating-custom-user-model-django/

first create your own forms:

```
# appname/forms.py

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from appname.models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given email and
    password.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)
        del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("email",)

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)
        del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
```

then use those forms:

```
# appname/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from appname.models import CustomUser
from appname.forms import CustomUserChangeForm, CustomUserCreationForm

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference the removed 'username' field
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    ordering = ('email',)

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: the PermissionsMixin from the example was helpful as well